# I can't show my array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have some simple code in JavaScript. I was going to create code to add first name, last name and age of students from the client by click on "Add Student" button, and show the list of students including the one just added by clicking on the "Show Students" button.

The add action is successful, but when I click on "Show Students" button it just shows me a table without any `information(First Name,Last Name,Age)`.

```js
var students = new Array();
var i = 0;

function AddStudent()
{
    var patt = /i[a-z]/;
    var Fname = prompt("enter  first name");
    var Lname = prompt("enter last name");
    var Age = prompt("enter age"); 
    var std= {fname : Fname,lname : Lname,age : Age }
    students[i++] =std;
}
    
function ShowStudents()
{
    var table = "<table style='background-color:greenyellow; border:solid;'>";
    table += "<tr><th>نام</th><th>نام خانوادگی</th><th>سن</th></tr>"
    for( var j=0;j<students.length;j++)
    {                                                      
        table += "<tr>"
        table += "<td>" + students[j].fname +"</td>"
        table += "<td>" + students[j].lname + "</td>"
        table += "<td>" + students[j].age + "</td>"
        table +="</tr>"
    }
    table += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("ShowStudents").innerHTML = table;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Add Student"  onclick="AddStudent();"/>
    <input type="button" value="Show Students"  onclick="ShowStudents();"/>
<div id="ShowStudents"></div>
```

Comment: Well, the snippet works...so were you missing something in your original code?

Comment: Seems to be working.

Comment: Works fine for me. Is this snippet the same as your actual code?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your browser can not execute instructions without " **;** " , so try to add it in this lines :

```
table += "<tr><th>نام</th><th>نام خانوادگی</th><th>سن</th></tr>"
for( var j=0;j<students.length;j++)
    {                                                      
        table += "<tr>"
        table += "<td>" + students[j].fname +"</td>"
        table += "<td>" + students[j].lname + "</td>"
        table += "<td>" + students[j].age + "</td>"
        table +="</tr>"
    }
```

because for me it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

i had some comment in my js page and  useless functions.finally i clean the comment and useless functions and it worked!